# Снниффер и SSL соединение

Tags: ssl

Написал две связки одна клиент TCP сервер TCP
Вторая связка Клиент SSL сервер SSL смотрю пакеты снниффером(SmartSniffer) соответственно у первой связки пакеты  и от клиента к серверу и от сервера к клиенту видны в голом виде(оно и понятно)

Что я должен увидеть в связке SSL (я там вижу одно подключение от клиента к сервера(то есть от сервера к клиенту не вижу вообще) и от клиента к серверу пакеты выводит пустые все ли верно? или же должны пакеты показываться в зашифрованном виде?)

Comment: SSL тоже работает на TCP. Он прослойка между протоколом приложения и TCP.

Comment: иными словами, на уровне TCP ничего не должно поменяться, пакеты все так же ходят туда сюда, просто содержимое будет зашифровано.

Comment: Я понимаю что это прослойка, все понял мой косяк я в теории то знал что должны доходить (не активировал снниффер просто вот почему не показывало вообще)

Comment: тогда я знаю как ответить на вопрос :)

Comment: ответил спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения сниффера разницы быть не должно на уровне ТСР (только в содержимом пакетов), скорее всего вы просто забыли его активировать.